# Template does not load all data onRendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, subscription

I have an awful bug and can't fix it. I try to load all users using Users.find() into one of layout sub-templates. The thing is that sometimes it does not load all users. Most of the time it load only currently logged one. While typing Users.find() in chrome console gives me all users and it works fine. May be data does not have time to load onRendered ? Here is the screenshot of a code. Thanks for any help !
[image]

Comment: Hi Alexander! First question, do you have the 'autopublish' package installed? It's installed in meteor by default, but it's recommended that you remove it. If you've removed that, be sure to publish your users from the server!

Comment: Code within onRendered is only ever executed once when the template is rendered. Unless you destroy the template it won't execute your code if you revisit the page.

Comment: @DustinStiles Hi, I uninstalled autopublish package and I published data.  L4zl0w, what do you suggest do to then ?

Comment: Alexander, if you had autopublish installed, then it wouldn't be contributing to this error. Try placing that code in 'onCreated' instead, or make a dedicated helper for it. The code dealing with the (nav items?) can stay, but move the rest out.

Comment: Create a helper. OnCreated is the same, it only gets executed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a template helper. For example:

```
helpers: {
  users() {
    return Meteor.users.find()
  }
}
```